# Is there any type of liquid, other than mercury, that PTFE teflon is known to "float" to the surface in?

Tags: density

The specific gravity of PTFE teflon is roughly 2.3. I have a 3/8" diameter sphere made up of entirely PTFE teflon, and I would like for it to float to the surface when dropped into a liquid.

Does anyone know of a liquid, other than mercury, that will allow this feat to be achievable?

(I prefer that the liquid be both non-toxic and inexpensive)

Comment: Gallium as well, presumably.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerici_solution - unfortunately toxic and expensive. That aside, I know that caesium chloride is used for centrifugation purposes although I'm not sure what's the highest density it can reach (lazy to calculate it right now).

Comment: Tetrabromomethane - Density: 3.42 g/cm³

Comment: $\ce{CHBr3}$ or $\ce{CH2I2}$ would do as well.

Comment: I don't think cesium chloride is quite dense enough (in aqeeous solution).  Cesium bromide might do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Various liquids are denser than $2.2\rm~\frac{g}{cm^3}$. $\ce{CBr2F2}$ is one of them with fairly low toxicity. Check out halons.